# Testing async fire-and-forget methods in Java 8

Tags: java, integration-testing, completable-future

I'm trying to write an integration test that involves a method that includes a fire-and-forget completion stage method in it in Java 8. The app code looks something like the following:

```
public CompletionStage<User> createAndStoreUser() {
    return createUser()
            .thenApply(this::store)
            .thenApply(user -> {
                findTeam(user)
                    .thenAccept(team -> { // fire and forget
                        thirdPartyClient.enqueue(team); 
                    })
                    .handle(swallow(t -> log.error("Enqueue team failed", t)));
                return user;
            })
    })
```

Currently my integration test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testCreateAndStoreUser() {
    User user = createAndStoreUser().toCompletableFuture().join();
  
    ItThirdPartyClient thirdPartyClient = itThirdPartyClient();
    assertThat(thirdPartyClient.getQueue(), hasSize(1));
}
```

But this isn't guaranteed to pass every time because the enqueue call is in a different thread and may not have completed by the time the assertion is made. Is there any way to force the nested `CompletionStage` to complete just for testing purposes, but not in the actual app where we want to fire-and-forget?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options and library that you can use to "wait" for the result or better say, avoid the mean thread complete the test method before you can assert your async result:

- If you use Java Futures you can use the blocking methods to block the main thread until the future is complete, be aware that this can be blocked forever.
- If you can provide the Executor to your async method you can use a synchronous Executor in your unit test and an asynchronous executor in your production code.
- In other hand you can use some library to test this

  - The first and easier solution is use CountDownLatch but you will found error very early when you try to return the assert result from your asynchronous thread to the main thread.
  - My choice is concurrent unit https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit a very good explanation can be found here https://github.com/playframework/play-java-ebean-example/blob/2.6.x/test/ModelTest.java
  - Another good option is https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility you can see some example here https://github.com/playframework/play-java-ebean-example/blob/2.6.x/test/ModelTest.java